# Verify my proof

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathbf{f:A \to B}$ and $\mathbf{g:B \to C}$.

Prove that if $\mathbf{f}$ and $\mathbf{g}$ are surjective functions,then
the composition $\mathbf{g \circ f}$ is also surjective.

$\mathbf{Proof:}$

Let ${f}$ be  surjective, then ${(\forall b \in B) (\exists a \in A) (f(a)=b)}$.

Let ${g}$ be  surjective, then ${(\forall c \in C) (\exists b \in B) (g(b)=c)}$.

${g \circ f}$ is defined because the codomain of f, is equivalent with the domain of g, so it follows =>

Since ${g \circ f:A \to C}$ and,  ${g \circ f=g(f(a))}$, it follows that ${ (\forall c \in C)(\exists a \in A)(g(f(a)=c)).}$
which leads to conclusion that ${g \circ f}$ is also surjective.

Comment: The reader has to do too much on their part to verify. Your proof should not require verification on the reader's part. Said a better way, your current proof requires the reader to piece things together.

Comment: In my opinion, it needs rewritten. How do you show that $g \circ f$ is surjective? You explained that $g \circ f$ is a map from $A$ to $C$. You mentioned that $(\forall c \in C)(\exists a \in A)(f(f(a))=c)$, but could you elaborate a bit more? It would be good to start off with, "Let $c \in C$," say some more, and then end with "there exists an $a \in A$ such that $g(f(a))=c$. Thus, $g \circ f$ is surjective."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition of composition, $g \circ f \colon A \to C$. Let $c \in C$. Since $g$ is surjective, there exists a $b \in B$ such that $g(b)=c$. Since $f$ is surjective, there exists an $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$. Thus, $c = g(b)=g(f(a))=(g\circ f)(a)$. Since $c$ was arbitrary, $g \circ f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are concluding too hastely.

It is better to say: Let $c\in C$, then we can find a $b\in B$ such that $g(b)=c$ (because $g$ is surjective), but then we can $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$ (because $f$ is surjective), so we found $a\in A$ such that $(g\circ f)(a)=g(f(a))=g(b)=c$.
Therefore $g\circ f$ is surjective.